# iPad 1 "400 BadRequest" with sendAsynchronousRequest, all working on iPad 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection

I have a server with some api, and I'm using this api with iPad as a client. The code is as follows:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://***/api/user"]];
    req.HTTPMethod = @"put";
    req.HTTPBody = data; // it is string data from json dictionary

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSString *userData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//...
    }];
```

All is working on iPad 3, but when I'm trying to test that code on iPad 1, there is a error. To be more specific: my server returning only JSON, even if there are some errors, so I can see if the error is on client or on server side. So, normally, userData should contain some string with dictionary:

```
{ "auth": 1, "email":"some@mail.com", "error": 0}
```

sometimes server can return (if I try to send incorrect auth data to it):

```
{ "auth": 0, "email":"", "error": 400, "errorMessage":"Bad Request"}
```

but what I am getting on iPad 1 is the html string:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a bit confused, because there are exactly the same options, the same internet connection, but the behaviors of iPad 1 and iPad 3 are different. Important note: iPad 1 has iOS 5.1.1, iPad 3 has 6.1. There should be a very simple solution, but I can not figure it out. I am not also sure if the model of iPad does actually matter. Also, I tried synchronous request and it did not worked too...

Comment: Remark: According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html, HTTP methods are case-sensitive, so it should be `@"PUT"`.

Comment: @MartinR WOW that worked! amazing! i almost got crazy about that. Strange behavior as for me, though, I hoped that Cocoa takes all work about cases of letters. Write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html, HTTP methods are case-sensitive, so you should use

```
req.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
```

It seems that iOS 6 converts the request method to upper-case automatically, and iOS 5 doesn't (one could check that with a network monitor).

Comment: vise versa then, iOS 6 converts and iOS 5 does not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @medvedNick: Oh yes, of course - I have fixed that in the answer.